# Any example of changing menus and supporting closing for an 'AllActive' tabbed application?

Tags: tabcontrol, caliburn.micro

I'm a CM newbie and trying to get my head around CM. I am building an application where each tab allows the user different functionality for accessing a server where the active work in all tabs (if any is active) could be running async to each other so the shell is an "Conductor.Collection.AllActive" which I hope was the correct choice. I am looking for suggestions or an sample in two areas -

1. I would like to have the main shell own the application menu and the tab control, and to change the  application menuitems depending on the tab selected and then have the menuitem clicks routed to the respective VM for the tab.
2. Since all tabs could potentially be doing active work simultaneously, I am hoping for an example of how the VM on each tab can participate in helping to decide (via dialogs to the user) if the application can be closed if the close menuitem or the application X icon is clicked. Or if the close should be cancelled per the user response (e.g. they say 'no' since there are unsaved files).

Any examples and suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Well I have the closing stuff working well (after getting more sleep and overriding CanClose in the Shell VM) but could use some suggestions on context sensitive menus in the shell when I switch from tab to tab changing viewmodels.

One approach I'm thinking of is to bind the main menu and supply a whole new menu set when a tab changes but I'm unclear on how to attach a "cal:Message.Attach" property with an action to a MenuItem control. Then I guess the ShellViewModel would publish a message to the TabXXXViewModel to handle the MenuItem click.

Advice on any other approach appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone throw me some rope? I promise to not hang myself with it. Some ideas I can try? A best practice?

There is nothing in the doc or articles I've read that talks about how to compose an application with a top level menu where the menuitems are context sensitive to the different ViewModel on each tab. I'm not sure where to start with this.

Do it all in code (do I just use regular events and not use CM for this) or should I try to do in xaml and VM code and somehow get CM to wire them up?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Well I have a workaround that was easy - just put another menu on each tab. Not the look I eventually want to keep as I'd prefer just one application level menu on top that dynamically changed for each tab. See http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/361609 where there was a bit additional discussion.

Comment: Created a sample of how you might do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [sample](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmwpftabmenu/src) of a possible way to do this.  Using a `SharedViewModel` that contains a collection of `MenuItems`.  The `SharedViewModel` is injected into the `ShellViewModel` and each `TabViewModel`.  The Menu control binds to the collection of `MenuItems`.

When a tab's `OnActivate` fires the Menu items can be updated by the `TabViewModel`.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MenuItemViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

  <Menu IsMainMenu="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SharedViewModel.MenuItems}" />
```

SharedViewModel:

```
 public class SharedViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private List<MenuItemViewModel> _menuItems;

        public List<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems
        {
            get { return _menuItems; }
            set
            {
                _menuItems = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MenuItems);
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of a TabViewModel updating the Menu:

```
 protected override void OnActivate()
        {
            base.OnActivate();

            SharedViewModel.MenuItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>
                                            {
                                                new MenuItemViewModel
                                                    {
                                                        Header = "MainMenuItem1",
                                                        MenuItems =
                                                            new List<MenuItemViewModel>
                                                                {
                                                                    new MenuItemViewModel {Header = "SubMenuItem1"},
                                                                    new MenuItemViewModel {Header = "SubMenuItem2"},
                                                                }
                                                    },
                                                    new MenuItemViewModel
                                                    {
                                                        Header = "MainMenuItem2",
                                                        MenuItems =
                                                            new List<MenuItemViewModel>
                                                                {
                                                                    new MenuItemViewModel {Header = "SubMenuItem1"},
                                                                    new MenuItemViewModel {Header = "SubMenuItem2"},
                                                                }
                                                    }
                                            };
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Derek! Looks interesting. I'll review, try, and give some feedback or mark as answer in a couple days as I've got my hands full for a bit putting up servers at a new hosting provider.

Comment: No problem, if you get stuck on handling actions/events, let me know, there are various ways to do that.